# How to hide/show td based on drop down menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a table having 5 or 6 td. The data in table is generated by 3 drop down menus with a Go button. When I set values in all the three drop downs, it shows me result in table.
But the problem is If i don't select a value in one or two of drop downs and set it to null, it should not show me that column in the table. I am trying it with javascript but i don't know how to do.
Here is my code for HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#go").click(function() {
    var select1 = document.getElementById("select1").value;
    var select2 = document.getElementById("select2").value;
    var select3 = document.getElementById("select3").value;;
  });

  if (select1 == null) {
    document.getElementByClass('select1td').style.display = none;
  }
  if (select2 == null) {
    document.getElementByClass('select2td').style.display = none;
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="select1" name="select1" style="width: 190px; display: block;">
  <option selected value="" disabled="disabled">Select an option</option>
  <?php 
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT name FROM tbl1 ";
            
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        
        echo "<option  class='name' value=' " . $row['name'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
<label>Lot Name</label>
<select id="select2" name="select2" style="width: 190px; display: block;">
  <option selected value="" disabled="disabled">Select an option</option>
  <?php 
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT course FROM tbl1 ";
            
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        
        echo "<option  class='course' value=' " . $row['course'] ."'>" . $row['course'] ."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>

<!-- and also a third drop down menu-->


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="select1td">
      <?php echo $row["name"]; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="select2td">
      <?php echo $row["course"]; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="select3td">
      <?php echo $row["reg"]; ?>
    </td>
</table>
```

Comment: I have to show If(select==null){then display that td i.e. column to none}

Comment: please consider using `MySQLi` or `PDO` extensions. The **OLD** `MySQL` extension is deprecated and not recommended to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed your original javascript code to jquery. You can check empty values with `if(myvalue)`. This works because javascript will see the value of an empty string as false. You can also do `if(myvalue !== '')` this checks if `myvalue` is not an empty string.

Also you wrote your if statements outside of the onclick event handler. Therefore the code was executed on the ready event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#go").on('click', function() {
    $('#select1').val() ? $('.select1td').show() : $('.select1td').hide();
    $('#select2').val() ? $('.select2td').show() : $('.select2td').hide();
    $('#select3').val() ? $('.select3td').show() : $('.select3td').hide();
  
    /* This is an alternative notation if you prefer this.
    
    if ($('#select1').val()) {
      $('.select1td').show();
    } else {
      $('.select1td').hide();
    }

    if ($('#select2').val()) {
      $('.select2td').show();
    } else {
      $('.select2td').hide();
    }

    if ( $('#select3').val()) {
      $('.select3td').show();
    } else {
      $('.select3td').hide();
    }
    
    */
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option value=''>no value</option>
  <option value='something'>value</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
  <option value=''>no value</option>
  <option value='something'>value</option>
</select>

<select id="select3">
  <option value=''>no value</option>
  <option value='something'>value</option>
</select>

<button id="go">Go</button>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="select1td">select1td</td>
    <td class="select2td">select2td</td>
    <td class="select3td">select3td</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can u please give me an example of how to do all this with data in table coming from database?

Comment: @stcara It's a bit unclear what you mean? Can you edit your question and describe in detail what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

In JQuery you can use `element.toggle();`

But is ok with javascript(element.style.display).

I think i see your problem, you write:

```
document.getElementByClass('select1td').style.display=none; //wrong
```

to get an element that has a specific class you must do like that:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('select1td')[index].style.display=none;
```

When you select a class you are selecting more than one element, you select an array of elements even you have only 1 element in array.
That is why you must specify a index.
Remember that in arrays index starts from 0(for taking the first element you must select element with index 0 like that):
document.getElementsByClassName('select1td')[0].style.display=none;

Improvement!
You can have only one class for those 3 td elements.

```
<table>
<tr>   
<td class="selecttd"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
<td class="selecttd"><?php echo $row["course"]; ?></td>
<td class="selecttd"><?php echo $row["reg"]; ?></td>
</table>
```

And you select each one like that:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('selecttd')[0.style.display=none;//for the first one
document.getElementsByClassName('selecttd')[0].style.display=none;//second
document.getElementsByClassName('selecttd')[0].style.display=none;//third
```

Another Improvement!

You can use `document.querySelector()` //with this you can select all kind of elements for example by tag name,class,id,:

```
document.querySelector("td");//select the first td
document.querySelectorAll(".class")[2];//selects the third element from class
document.querySelector("#id");//selects an element by id
```

Your javascript code ca be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#go").click(function(){
 var select1=document.getElementById("select1").value;
  var select2=document.getElementById("select2").value;
   var select3=document.getElementById("select3").value;
   ;
      });

      if(select1==null){
document.querySelectorAll('selecttd')[0].style.display=none;
      }
      if(select2==null){
document.querySelectorAll('selecttd')[1].style.display=none;
      }
      }); 
  </script>
```

And HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>   
<td class="selecttd"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
<td class="selecttd"><?php echo $row["course"]; ?></td>
<td class="selecttd"><?php echo $row["reg"]; ?></td>
</table>
```

JQuery example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#go").click(function(){
 var select1=$(#select1").val;
  var select2=$(#select2").val;
   var select3=$(#select3").val;
   ;
      });

      if(select1==null){
$('.selecttd')[0].toggle();
      }
      if(select2==null){
$('.selecttd')[1].toggle();
      }
      });
```

I hope this was helpful! 
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

By the way, it is not recommended to use mysql* functions anymore. They are deprecated. **Use mysqli* instead.**